# How to convert an XML string into a DOMDocument in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-parsing

I got an example XML string from a customer, which I would like to transform to a DOMDocument. I can't seem to get the first node right though....

The string looks like this;

```
<ev:Events xmlns:ev="xsdEvents" xsi:schemaLocation="xsdEvents [url]" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Node>
        <OtherNode>value</OtherNode>
    </Node>
</ev:Events>
```

How would I set this up the proper way via DOMDocument in PHP?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The answer would be to use [`DOMDocument::loadXml()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) but I refuse to give that as answer since it should be the first thing on Google and there is a gazillion usage examples for DOM on SO anyway. Please clarify your question if there is more to it than just "How to load XML with DOMDocument".

Comment: I agree with @Gordon. I don't think we should duplicate well known official documentation. I might be wrong... Retagging because it has nothing to do with XSLT.

Comment: @Alejandro; all node names etc. in my example are dummies to protect the official documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant PHP documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Well, loading a XML string to a DOMDocument object is not quite that hard -- you'll just have to use [**`DOMDocument::loadXML()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php).

For example, in your case, you'd use :

```
$string = <<<XML
<ev:Events xmlns:ev="xsdEvents" xsi:schemaLocation="xsdEvents [url]" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Node>
        <OtherNode>value</OtherNode>
    </Node>
</ev:Events>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($string);
```

Then, accessing your data is just a matter of using the relevant DOM methods.

For example, to extract the value of your `<OtherNode>` node, you could use :

```
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('OtherNode');
if ($items->length > 0) {
  var_dump( $items->item(0)->nodeValue );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but indeed it seems I didn't explain my (first) question properly.

The file I received was just an example. What I am trying to do is build the same structure as the file has, but by using DOMDocument.